# User access for specific routes with parameters

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2, angular-guards

I am using Angular with firebase. In my app users can create "projects" and invite another users to that "project" in other words one project can have multiple users. I have `user` collection and `project` collection in firestore.

**User collection**

```
users/userID/ -> { name: string }
```

in `users` collection are documents which have id value and data (just name)

**Project collection**

```
project/projectID/ -> 
{
  projectName: String,
  users: [
    { 
     userID: (here id of user),
     role: String
    }
  ]
```

in `project` collection are documents which have id value and data. Data are projectName and array of users. In this array of users i have ids of users that can access the project.

**Scenario**

User signIn to my app, now he is in simple intro page at route `/hello`. Now user can see his projects, when he click at some project he will be routed to this path `/project/:id` and here he can use other functions e.g. `/project/:id/overview`. It's similar to firebase console `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/myprojectid/authentication/users` :) I hope I just clarify what i am trying to achieve. If you are still confused let me know in comments.

**What's the problem?**

In my project this works good, but problem is when someone copy **id** of different project to url and hits enter. I want to prevent users to get to others users projects so if i enter this path `/project/notMyProject/overview` in url, I should be redirected or something. Hmm thats easy, just create router guard I thought. So I started...

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'project/:pid', component: ProjectComponent, 
   children: [
    { path: '', component: OverviewComponent}, 
    { path: 'users', component: ProjectUsersComponent, }, 
   ],
   canActivate: [ProjectGuard, AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: '', component: PageComponent }
];
```

**project.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../core/auth.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
 AngularFirestore,
 AngularFirestoreDocument
} from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectGuard implements CanActivate {

private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
item: Observable<any>;

constructor(
 private auth: AuthService,
 private afs: AngularFirestore,
) {}

canActivate(
 next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
 state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

  this.itemDoc = this.afs.doc<any>.(`project/${next.paramMap.get('pid')}`);

  this.item = this.itemDoc.valueChanges();

  this.item.subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response)
    response.users.forEach( (element) => {
      if(element.userID == this.auth.user.subscribe( data => { return data.uid })) {
        return true;
      }
    })
  })
 }
}
```

and here I am. I quite new to rxjs and all that observable stuff. That code is asynchronous and I don't know how to make this work,I am getting error that I have to return Observable or boolean...

**Question**

Is my general approach to this specific problem correct? Is there some better options that I should consider? How other pages solve this problem e.g. firebase (try this [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/a/authentication/users)). And if my solution is good can you help me with my project.guard?? Thank you very much

I tried to describe my problem as clear as possible. If you missing some informations, please let me know in comments and I will update my question. I searched many hours how to solve this but i could not find anything or I just use wrong search keywords. I hope this will help others too.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you can be sure(almost) you are doing it wrong with `Observables` when you see them:

1. Doing a nested `subscribe`, and
2. Assigning a results to a `subsrciption` aka `var result == someObservables.subscribe()`

And these are the two exact mistake you have in the code.

The reason mistake 1 happens is because most of the time `Observables` are asynchronous, and which is also your case, and your code **cannot ensure** the sequence the results will be back. Your code runs synchronously, and cannot deliberately wait for the execution of the async tasks.  That is why `operators` exist (maps, filters, concatMap, etc), so that you deal with the `Observables` (per se), and not inside the subscription when the `Observables` finally emit its values.

Mistake 2 is not uncommon, as for someone who's new to `Observables` will always think that the results of the Observables comes from the function of the `Observables` - they don't. They comes in the parameter in the subscription callback function:

```
var thisIsSubscriptionNotResult = myObservable.subscribe(results=>{
    var thisisTheRealResult = results;
}
```

After understanding the two mistakes, its fairly easy to solve the issues in your code. You will need the help of `combineLatest` here, to combine two different `observables`.

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    this.itemDoc =  this.afs.doc<any>(`project/${next.paramMap.get('pid')}`);
    return Observable
        .combineLatest(this.itemDoc.valueChanges, this.auth.user)
        .map(([response, authUser]) => {
            return response.users.some(x => x.userID === authUser.uid);
        });
}
```

What the code above does is that it combines the two Observables, `this.itemDoc.valueChanges` and also `this.auth.user`. But the angular router guard needs a `Observable<boolean>`, so you need to map them in order to transform it to a boolean.

If you are using rxjs 6, the syntax is slightly different:

```
return combineLatest(this.itemDoc.valueChanges, this.authU.user)
    .pipe(
        map(([response, authUser]) => {
            return response.users.any(x => x.userID === authUser.uid);
        })
    );
```